# How to install a bulb guard on a bulb in a porcelain lampholder

Tags: light-fixture, code-compliance

I am DIY-ing the electrical work in a remodel I'm doing.  When I submitted forms to the township for inspection, the electrician on staff there said that the 4 light fixtures I'd added to 4 closets need to have covers to be to code.

I have 8'+ ceilings, so it's a bit annoying.  I would rather not have globes.  3 of the fixtures are pull-chain and they all have an outlet on the side, which a globe would cover up.

I discovered "bulb guards", which are either a metal or plastic cage that clamps down on the light fixture, but these porcelain fixtures taper toward the socket, so there's no way to securely affix them.

I've had 2 thoughts:

1. I could use socket extensions and clamp the bulb guard onto the extension, but that just seems silly.
2. I found these ugly plastic cages that actually fit between the porcelain fixture and the electrical box.

Neither option seems ideal.  I like the look of the metal cages, but the plastic one that connects with the box seems "safer".  Are there any other options short of a globe that covers up the outlet?

Actually, while I was typing this, the township electrical inspector called me back and said that the socket extension idea is no-good code-wise.  So does anyone know of a way to install a nice metal cage that properly affixes to a porcelain light fixture?

Comment: When you say "porcelain light fixture" -- are you referring to a *keyless lampholder*? Also, have you considered replacing the fixtures in question with fairly inexpensive LEDs?

Comment: seems like a waste of your time trying to kludge something together ... just get sockets that accept bulb guards or get a ceiling fixture with a cover

Comment: It's a Leviton porcelain lamp holder. It has a pull string and an outlet on the side. I wanted those features and I didn't want something plastic, so I'm annoyed I have to change it. They're all in closets on 8' ceilings. I don't really care about a cover, but if I have to have one, I'd prefer the metal bulb guards. I was just hoping there might exist an acceptable way to attach those guards to be to code, like maybe a collar that fits on it or something.

Comment: We're also trying to stay true to the 1920s aesthetic of the house as possible.

Comment: It looks like Eaton makes a fixture with an outlet that a metal cage will clamp to.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose Yeah, that might work. I just hope the clamp doesn't crack the ceramic. Thanks, I'll check it out. It's annoying though that Home Depot happily sells something that is impossible to install to code with all its features usable.